# Is it possible to do a repeated measure two-way analysis of variance using only summary statistics(MEAN, SD)?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, anova

Is it possible to do a repeated measure two-way analysis of variance using only summary statistics(MEAN, SD)?
I would like to proceed with a repeated measure analysis of variance.

The following is the format of the data.

```
ID <- seq(15)
G <- c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5),rep("C",5))
D <- rep(c(rep("T",3),rep("F",2)),3)
V1 <- round(rnorm(15)*10,1)
V2 <- round(rnorm(15)*10,1)
V3 <- round(rnorm(15)*10,1)
DF <- data.frame(ID,G,D,V1,V2,V3)
```

ID  = Classification of individual observation targets 
G = GRADE (GROUP1)
D = GROUP2
V1 = value in time 1
V2 = value in time 2
V3 = value in time 3

Assuming that the original data is the same as the above DF, the information I can know is as follows.

```
P<-DF %>% 
  group_by_at(c("G")) %>% 
  select(paste0("V", rep(c(1,2,3), each = 1))) %>% 
  summarise_all(list(mean = function(x) {mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)},
                     sd = function(x) {sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)},
                     median = function(x) {median(x, na.rm = TRUE)},
                     n = function(x) {sum(!is.na(x))},
                     meanSQ=function(x){mean(x^2, na.rm = TRUE)}))
```

meanSQ = E[x^2]

Can you perform a two-way analysis of variance with just this data output?
I would be very grateful if you could tell me how.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I think that in order to be able to do a repeated measures ANOVA, you would need at least the subject-level means and std devs as well. Otherwise I don't see how you can estimate the within-subjects variance.